# How to print line breaks in Python Django template

Tags: python, html, django, templates

```
{'quotes': u'Live before you die.\n\n"Dream as if you\'ll live forever, live as if you\'ll die today"\n\n"Love one person, take care of them until you die. You know, raise kids. Have a good life. Be a good friend. Try to be completely who you are, figure out what you personally love and go after it with everything you\'ve got no matter how much it takes." -Angelina Jolie.'}
```

Notice my dictionary has line breaks in them: **\n**

How do I display my template with those line breaks?

{{quotes|withlinebreaks\n}}

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Use the [`linebreaks`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) filter.

For example:

```
{{ value|linebreaks }}
```

If value is `Joel\nis a slug`, the output will be `<p>Joel<br />is a slug</p>`.

Answer (score 41):

You can also use the [`linebreaksbr`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr) filter to simply convert all newlines to `<br>` 
 without additional `<p>`.

Example:

```
{{ value|linebreaksbr }}
```

If `value` is `Joel\nis a slug`, the output will be `Joel<br>is a slug`.

The difference from [Ignacio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316038/318359) (`linebreaks` filter) is that `linebreaks` tries to guess the paragraphs in a text and wrap every paragraph in `<p>` where `linebreaksbr` simply [substitutes newlines with `<br>`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5033999153f7303a18d94ea2f08ed78545c0f3df/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L434).

Here's a demo:

```
>>> from django.template.defaultfilters import linebreaks
>>> from django.template.defaultfilters import linebreaksbr
>>> text = 'One\nbreak\n\nTwo breaks\n\n\nThree breaks'
>>> linebreaks(text)
'<p>One<br />break</p>\n\n<p>Two breaks</p>\n\n<p>Three breaks</p>'
>>> linebreaksbr(text)
'One<br />break<br /><br />Two breaks<br /><br /><br />Three breaks'
```

Comment: This is better I don't know why people vote for wrong Answers.

Comment: This solution helped preserve my CSS settings. The top solution using {{value|linebreaks}} ignored them.

Comment: "This is better I don't know why people vote for wrong Answers." How dare they do that :-D But I agree. I prefer having the br tags as linebreaks since p seems to do weird things with text in particular html containers.

Answer (score 2):

All of these answers don't explicitly mention that `{{ value|linebreaksbr }}` should be used in the display template ie the get request not the post request.

So if you had a template to display say post.details, it would be

```
<h4>Below are the post details</h4>

{{ post.details|linebreaksbr }}
```

And not in the post form

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|linebreaksbr }}
    <button>Save post</button>
</form>
```

Had this same issue and after figuring it our decided that someone outthere might find it handy.
Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

for some reason i can't change this value

```
val = """
Brand AER \nDetail Material Kuningan berlapis emas chrome dan powder coating \nTipe Produk Keran Shower \nWarna Emas \nMaterial Kuningan \nUkuran Kemasan 12cm x 19cm x 13cm \nUkuran Barang 12cm x 19cm x 13cm \nBerat 2kg \nManual Instruksi instalasi manual dapat didownload di link berikut:https://aer.co.id/products/aer-kran-shower-panas-dingin-luxury-series-sah-sr1/?attachment_id=10954&amp;download_file=5e267c93cdc76&amp;_wpnonce=28db09bc61
"""
```

which has '\n' in it with linebreaks or linebreaksbr filter
i've tried this

```
{ val|linebreaks }}
{ val|linebreaksbr }}
```

the `val` stays the same
then i tried @AndrewFox answer and did this and it worked for me

Change `\n` to `<br>` and autoescape off

```
{% autoescape off %}
   {{ val }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score -5):

Use `'<br>'` instead of `/n`.

If necessary, you can do a `.replace('/n', '<br>')`.